# Is there some kind of open javascript library for BigQuery UDFs (for Google Analytics data)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

As in topic. Perphaps some of you have stumbled upon the javascript library available in public or list of examples that would be particulary useful while using BigQuery with Google Analytics data? Interesting blog articles count too :)

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you are trying to solve? The question might be too general for anyone to make a meaningful suggestion. Most transformations that you might want to do with JavaScript functions can probably be accomplished using SQL instead.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard there is nothing particular that I am trying to solve - the question is general

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is [BigQuery Analytics Cookbook](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089)
It has quite a wide range of useful use-cases / examples

```
Query optimization
Tips and best practices
    •   Query multiple tables
    •   3 Days using comma separated table names
    •   Last 7 Days using TABLE_DATE_RANGE
    •   Last 3 Months using TABLE_DATE_RANGE
    •   Last 1 Year using TABLE_DATE_RANGE
    •   Specific Date Range
    •   Last 6 Days plus Today’s data (intraday) using multiple TABLE_DATE_RANGE
Basic query examples
•   Total [metric] per [dimension]
•   Average bounce rate per [dimension]
•   Average number of product pageviews by purchaser type
•   Average number of transactions per purchaser
•   Average amount of money spent per session
•   Sequence of hits (pathing analysis)
•   Multiple custom dimensions at hit or session level
Advanced query examples
•   Products purchased by customers who purchased Product A (Classic Ecommerce)
•   Products purchased by customers who purchased product A (Enhanced Ecommerce)
•   Average number of user interactions before purchase
•   Percentage of stock sold per product
•   Profitability of each product
•   Real profitability of each product
```

Note: Using JS UDF can be [`expensive`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#best-practices-for-javascript-udfs) and also have quite a [`limitations`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limits) - so you should use them if you really need. In most (if not all ) reasonably practical cases - using pure BigQuery Standard SQL will be more than sufficient

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it is not useful for JavaScript UDFs that the question is about, as well as it does focus only on the not recommended version of SQL - legacy SQL

Comment: @user3853657 - sure, understood. to me  - looks like there is no any such library for bq udf (at least so far) - so I thought it woulds be really `useful` to point you to that cookbook. :o) of course - it is up to you to judge whether it is really useful or not for you. respect you opinion on this :o)